Error Anchor Test
I am getting the following error when running
anchor test
Error: target/idl/program.json doesn't exist. Did you run anchor build?
I've checked all the names of the program inside the cargo.toml file and they match.

in addition to checking if the names are correct, also check that the program types provider in your tests correctly match your workspace name
for example, if you initialized a program named new-program your TS types will be import { NewProgram } from "../target/types/new_program" which you can use to initialize your program const program = anchor.workspace.NewProgram as Program<NewProgram>;
running anchor deploy will also renegerate these types and the IDL if all fails.

Anchor deploy gives me this error Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

that's new. can you share the full logs by editing your question and also sharing your solana env config
